Is there an event listener for sources being added in Mapbox?
I've been playing around with Mapbox GL JS in my react app, and I'm noticing that there is sometimes a bit of latency after I call addSource vs it being queryable.
When the app loads on the browser:
this.map.current?.addSource('historic-source', {
  type: enums.DataType.GEOJSON,
  data: { type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [] }
});

Upon receipt of a websocket message from one of our servers, we want to manipulate 'historic-source':
const source = this.map.current?.getSource('historic-source') as mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource;

if (!source) {
  console.error(`MapComponent updateHistoricLayerSource Source with ID historic-source not found.`);
  return;
}

Upon several refreshes, I am seeing that I am often getting the console.error output stated above. It is hit and miss.
I am finding the documentation for Mapbox a little hard to follow - but I was wondering what the best way of handling this would be?
It would be great if there was an event-listener which could fire when a specific source is actually added. Is that a thing?
That way, I could load the initialisation of my websocket listener within the 'on' for this event-listener... so that any incoming messages can't cause any premature issues

Sounds like you have a race condition. Can you show more of your code? Specifically, when are you calling addSource and getSource?

When sources change, MapDataEvent is generated (see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/#mapdataevent)
